# Removal of text from a string using VBA

Tags: regex, vba

I am attempting to remove text from a list of values which looks like this:

```
3.5S
4PR
2.5
4
```

I have tried the following in VBA:

```
Function StripChar(Txt As String) As String
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
.Global = True
.Pattern = "\D"
StripChar = .Replace(Txt, "")
End With
End Function
```

However, this also removes the decimal points in my list, giving:

```
35
4
25
4
```

While I am aiming for:

```
3.5
4
2.5
4
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text characters are always *after* the numeric portion of the string then you can simply use the `Val()` function to return the number at the beginning of the string. If not and you want to stick with regular expressions then you can try setting your pattern to `(\d+\.?(\d?)+)` which should pick up decimal numbers anywhere in a string.